# CGLayers not blending

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

This is what I am trying to do: create two CGLayers, A and B. Put B over A, using a blend mode, get the resulting image.

This is the code

```
// Begin the drawing
CGLayerRef objectLayer;
CGContextRef fundoContext, objectContext;
CGRect backRect, objectRect;

CGFloat w = myImage.size.width;
CGFloat h = myImage.size.height;
CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(w, h);

backRect  = CGRectMake (0, 0, h, w);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sz);  
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
fundoLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext (context, sz, NULL);
fundoContext = CGLayerGetContext (fundoLayer);

CGContextDrawImage(fundoContext, backRect, myImage.CGImage);
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointMake(0,0), fundoLayer);



UIImage *myObject = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
 pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"]];


w = myObject.size.width;
h = myObject.size.height;
sz = CGSizeMake(w, h);

float centroW, centroH;

// centering
objectRect  = CGRectMake (((myImage.size.width - w) / 2 ),
((myImage.size.height - h) / 2 ), w, h);

centroW = myImage.size.width / 2;
centroH = myImage.size.height / 2;


//objectRect  = CGRectMake (0, 0, h, h);
objectLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext (context, sz, NULL);
objectContext = CGLayerGetContext (objectLayer);

// in theory this should set the blendmode of the top layer to screen…
CGContextSetBlendMode(objectContext, kCGBlendModeScreen);


CGContextDrawImage(objectContext, objectRect, myObject.CGImage);
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointMake(centroW, centroH), objectLayer);

resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

the result I get is that resultingImage is not equal to the composition of the two layers. In fact resultingImage is equal just to the first layer. The second layer is being ignored by this!!!

???

am I missing something?

thanks for any help.

Comment: probably just a typo:  objectoContext?

Comment: thanks. sorry about that. This was just a typo when I copied the code from Xcode to hear, as I had to change some variable languages I typed in my language to english, in order to clarify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming `myImage` is larger than `myObject`, since you're trying to center one within the other.

When you create `objectLayer`, it has the smaller size - that of `myObject`.

The rect `objectRect` is positioned to center the smaller image within the larger.

But when you call `CGContextDrawImage` on `myObject`, you use `objectRect` to position the image within the smaller layer -- this appears to be a mismatch.

So maybe the trouble is simply that, in the last `CGContextDrawImage` call, `objectRect` is positioning the second layer out of frame.

Comment: MY MAN!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thanks! After several hours looking at the code you cannot see things like that!